# Docker does not have internet inside containers. CentOS 7

Tags: centos, docker

Here i try to execute command to check outside world:

centos kernel:
3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

```bsh
628 ◯  docker run -it --rm -t alpine ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Here is info of drone CI within docker trying to access gitea:

```bsh
Login Failed. Post https://gitea.my-domain.ru/login/oauth/access_token: dial tcp: lookup gitea.my-domain.ru on 213.133.100.100:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:50701->213.133.100.100:53: i/o timeout
```

Also, I tried installing Sentry onpremise, it works, but no internet access also. It can't send webhooks to outside worls, all end up timeout or host not resolved.

Here is /etc/resolv.conf inside container:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Here is /etc/resolv.conf inside host machine:

```
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:1010
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9898
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9999
```

I have firewallcmd installed, but it has no special rules for docker, I did not add anything for docker.

Docker lines inside iptables -L

```
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
```

I could not find any useful info on the internet about this problem.

Comment: does your docker container have an IP address that is routed on the internet? or a private [RFC 
1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) address?   If the latter, and you're not doing any kind of masquerading or NAT, then there's no route for any host on the internet to get back to your container.